# While empty the Cart , Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

[Code Uploaded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SbS6w2Y-gl0GdccZXDPdmstJKMHZ3Y9x/view?usp=sharing)

when I am deleting Item from cart that error appearing from here

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 0):

One of the rules of react is never call react hooks inside child functions or don't call them conditionally.

You have to call them at the top inside a parent component's scope.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of `useEffect` present in `Totals` child function.

Either remove `useEffect` from `Totals` child function and implement its logic in parent function `Cart` or make `Totals` a separate component and use that component in `Cart`.